# JDBCRealm correctly configured but no successful connection

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, mariadb, jdbcrealm

I post this question after having searched thoroughly in Internet with no situation alike found. I'm trying to use a JDBCRealm to authenticate users in a simple test web application deployed with Tomat 7.0.42 and MariaDB 5.5 in a development environment. I've followed all the steps explained at [Tomcat's How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html) and this is what I have:

**My app's deployment descriptor:**

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/desautorizado.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Acciones</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/actions/*</url-pattern>           
    </web-resource-collection>

    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Paginas</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/sel_tipo_tabla.jsp</url-pattern>          
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>estandar</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>estandar</role-name>
</security-role>    

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/jsp/desautorizado.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>        
</login-config>
```

**Tomcat's conf/server.xml:**

```
<Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
   <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
      <Context docBase="MyAppStruts" path="/MyAppStruts" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyAppStruts">
         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
               driverName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
               connectionURL="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/desa"
               connectionName="ruben"
               connectionPassword="acceso"
               userTable="usuarios"
               userNameCol="usuario"
               userCredCol="password"
               userRoleTable="roles"
               roleNameCol="rol" />
      </Realm>
    </Context>        
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

It works perfectly if I use a UserDatabaseRealm instead (Tomcat's default which uses conf/tomcat-users.xml file). However, I always get redirected to the error page if I use a JDBCRealm, even when I introduce an existing user/password in the database.

I forgot to mention that I'm using Eclipse to deploy, so everything is relative to $CATALINA_BASE and **NOT** $CATALINA_HOME. In development environments, $CATALINA_BASE points to $(WORKSPACE_DIR)/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0. Thus, MariaDB driver jar file is in $(WORKSPACE_DIR)/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/lib/mariadb-java-client.jar and the public key certificate is in $(WORKSPACE_DIR)/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/hogar.keystore (no problem with this).

By watching the logs, I noticed that whenever I reset the server (only reset, even before launching first request to my app), the following line is written:

127.0.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2013:21:29:32 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" **404** 961

No error or exception is showed in Eclipse's console tab. I guess that Tomcat is unable to establish a connection to the database, but, why?

Answer (score 0):

I was just that the role value for my user in the database mismatched the value of the <security-role> and <auth-constraint>in my deployment descriptor.